# Passing elements between pages in C# Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, parameter-passing

First I pass content of the button from MainPage to Menu2:

```
private void Button2Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Create PassData object
        PassData passData = new PassData();

        // Set the InitializeData property from the button's content
        passData.Data = firstElement.Content;

        // Pass that object to Navigate
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Menu2), passData);

    }
```

Then I retrieve data within Menu2 page:

```
// pulling data from first page selection
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs args)
    {
        // Get the object passed as the second argument to Navigate
        PassData passData = args.Parameter as PassData;

        // Use that to initilize the button
        firstElement.Content = passData.Data;

        base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
    }
```

At this point button's content is passed without problems.

Then I want to pass that data back to MainPage again:

Menu2 code:

```
private void Button1Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Create PassData object
        PassData passData = new PassData();

        // Set the InitializeData property from the button's content
        passData.Data = firstElement.Content;

        // Pass that object to Navigate
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), passData);

    }
```

and I try to retrieve data in MainPage:

```
// pulling data from Menu2's button
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs args)
    {
        // Get the object passed as the second argument to Navigate
        PassData passData = args.Parameter as PassData;

        // Use that to initilize the button
        firstElement.Content = passData.Data;

        base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
    }
```

At this point I get an error on MainPage's line:

```
firstElement.Content = passData.Data;
```

The error says:

```
Null Reference Exception, Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: either your firstElement  or the passData object is null.

Comment: But how come? Shouldn't it have data assigned since it has already been passed on by mainpage?

Comment: It says that passData is null. But it should have whatever was in firstElement.Content right?

Answer (score 0):

So which one is the first page do you load ?

When you load the one in first time, `passData` will be null.

I guess you are working on UWP, you should create and pass a PassData() as argument in file `App.cs` when you navigate to MainPage.

Comment: I pass a PassData using class in separate cs file. First I load MainPage where passData is null. Then I navigate to Menu2 and firstElement.Content of MainPage is assigned to PassData. Then it is retrieved in Menu2. Since in Menu2 the firstElement.Content within that page gets PassData content assigned, I wanted to pass same data back to MainPage. At this point it seems that PassData loses firstElement.Content value.

Comment: Do I need a separate PassData() to send data back to MainPage?

Comment: @paddy can you paste your App.cs?

Comment: I didn't include anything within app.cs

Comment: @paddy so your app always get NullReferenceException when App navigate to MainPage (before your MainPage navigate to Menu2)

Comment: Yes. Main to Menu2 works. Only Menu2 to Main results in null object error

Comment: @paddy NOT Menu2 to Main, BUT App to Main.

Comment: So what should I do then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128018/discussion-between-cologler-and-paddy).